# Does an infinite integral converge when two functions converge

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $g\colon \mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$. Suppose $F(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} f(s)\,ds$ and $G(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} g(s)\,ds$ exist as real numbers.

Suppose $f(x)\rightarrow g(x)$ in the sense that for any $\epsilon$, there exists $X$ such that for any $x> X$, $\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert <\epsilon$. It it true that $F(x) \rightarrow G(x)$?

This seems like a simple question. My attempt was to start with saying, for $x$ large enough such that $\vert g(x) - f(x)\vert <\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, we have

\begin{equation}
\vert F(x) - G(x)\vert  \leq \int_{x}^{T}\vert f(s)-g(s)\vert ds + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \leq (T-x)\frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{equation}

where $T$ is large enough. Except, of course, $T$ can be arbitrarily large, which is a problem.

I would appreciate any help! (I think we have to somehow show the choice of $T$ does not depend on $x$?)

Comment: Do you mean a sequence of functions converging to $g$? Written like this $f$ and $g$ must be identical. To prove it assume there is $x>X$ such that $f(x)>g(x)=f(x)-\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon>0$ and you get a contradiction.

Comment: @AlbertoDebernardi I think he means that $\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x) - g(x)) = 0$. At least, that is what "for any $\epsilon$, there exists $X$ such that for any $x> X$, $\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert <\epsilon$" means, by definition.

Comment: @Arthur, yes that is correct

Comment: I understand now. If you take sufficiently good functions (say, smooth), $f$ and $g$, and those integrals exist as real numbers then $f(x)$ and $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. Try taking two different integrals you know that converge and see what happens.

Comment: @AlbertoDebernardi How do you know that $f(x)$ and $g(x) \to 0$? Even analytic functions doesn't necessarily do that. Take, for instance, $\sin(x^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, absolutely continuous

Comment: Let's get specific. E.g. $F(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{\int_{x}^{s}-r(\omega)d\omega}\,ds$ and $G(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-(s-x)r^{\star}}\,ds$ where $r\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $r\rightarrow r^{\star}$ where $r^{\star}$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\int_a^\infty f(s)\,ds$ converges, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^\infty f(s)\,ds=0$. In your situation, both $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ converge to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.